# Non-Hausdorff CGWH-group

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there a group $G$ which is at the same time a (compact-Hausdorff)-ly generated weakly Hausdorff space (or short CGWH space) such that inverse and product are continuous maps and the space is not Hausdorff?

Note that the group multiplication is a map from $G \times G$ to $G$. In the sense of this question, $G \times G$ denotes the product in the category of CGWH spaces. It is not necessarily equipped with the usual product topology.

Comment: Take the free CGWH group $FX$ on any non-Hausdorff CGWH space $X$.

Comment: @Tyrone Thank you for the quick answer. Can I find the definition of a free CGWH group somewhere? My search through the internet or to come up with the correct definition by myself were not successful.

Comment: You should find the details in [Lamartin's article](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://eudml.org/doc/268500&ved=2ahUKEwjuu9qhrPL9AhUCV2wGHcn0CFsQFnoECA4QAQ&usg=AOvVaw2P5ss5rIxe-neUUYaEGw7x). I can try to find a more specific reference tomorrow if you need.

Comment: Thanks, this article is already quite detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give this question the correct color, I give this proper answer. The mathematical part of this answer is purely based on [Tyrone](https://mathoverflow.net/users/54788/tyrone)'s comments.

Yes, there is a CGWH group which is not Hausdorff. This is shown in  [Lamartin's article](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://eudml.org/doc/268500&ved=2ahUKEwjuu9qhrPL9AhUCV2wGHcn0CFsQFnoECA4QAQ&usg=AOvVaw2P5ss5rIxe-neUUYaEGw7x) in Example 2.14.

The idea is the following: The forgetful functor from CGWH groups to CGWH spaces has a left adjoint $F$. Let $X$ be any non-Hausdorff CGWH space. By definition, $FX$ is a CGWH group. There is a natural continuous map $X\to FX$. This can be seen by explicitely constructing $FX$ or by taking the adjoint to the continuous group Homomorphism $\operatorname{id}: FX \to FX$. One can show that this map is a closed embedding. Therefore, $FX$ is not Hausdorff.